Retrieving "b5x-stateful-inline-icon" flag errored: timed out - falling back
I have this error message for my small Angular project. Do you know how to fix it please ?
Screen shot of the error message
I checked my code and i didn't find the solution. I expect to see a list of cocktails.
Thank you in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In my case, this was 1Password trying to inject javascript onto the page, not anything I had added to the page I'm authoring.

See https://1password.community/discussion/145003/console-error-retrieving-b5x-stateful-inline-icon-flag-errored-timed-out-falling-back.
